# Javascript iife angularjs example

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple controller which works absolutely fine.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('ProductController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.Message = "Hello World";
} ]);
```

However, if I want to put this inside a function, i.e.

```
(function () { 
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('ProductController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.Message = "Hello World";
} ]);
});
```

I get the following error
Error: ng:areq
Bad Argument
Argument 'ProductController' is not a function, got undefined

Html is like this

```
 <body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="ProductController">
  {{Message}}
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your iife is not correct, you are missing `invoking` part of iife(Immediately-**invoked** function expression), you are not `invoking` it

```
(function () { 
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('ProductController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.Message = "Hello World";
} ]);
})();
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
(function () { 
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('ProductController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.Message = "Hello World";
} ]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="ProductController">
  {{Message}}
</div>
</body>
```